# What happens if you roll a 7 before the barbarians reach the island?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

Accordingly to [these rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/CitiesAndKnights.pdf), when you roll a 7 before the first barbarians' arrival, you have to drop half of your deck, if you have more than 7 cards.

The rules in the Italian version of the game say that nothing happens when you roll a 7 before the barbarians arrival.

Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English rules are correct; you still must discard half your hand if you are holding too many cards. You can find the latest edition of the rulebook on catan.com [here](http://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_ck_5th_ed_rules_150303.pdf). It says;

> The robber cannot be moved until after the barbarians reach the island of Catan for the first time. Until the first barbarian attack, if you roll a "7", each player must check if he is holding too many cards as usual; however, you do not move the robber from the desert and you do not steal a card from another player.

Comment: ooh - when did they change that? I'm sure it always used to be that there was no special "before the first attack" rules.

Comment: @xorsyst I also don't remember learning that rule back when I learned Cities and Knights, back when the Soldiers were Soldiers and the game was "Settlers of Catan".

Comment: @Gendolkari - I may have learned it way back when Soldiers where Ritters and the game was "Die Siedler von Catan" :D.